# Make an Intent reliable for Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have this piece of code which was first implemented into a class that extends Activity and now that class extends Fragment and I don't know how to transform it.

This is my code:

```
 menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityTypes.this, ConnectionScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: Check the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) to learn how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code is now inside a Fragment, you simply have to replace ActivityTypes.this with getActivity().

Clarification: The first parameter of new Intent() requires a Context. Fragment doesn't extend Context. Calling getActivity() retrieves the container activity, which does extend Context.